# Merge two dataframes with similar coordinates by latitude and longitude

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf, data-wrangling

I have seen similar questions but all answers address merging two dataframes with different latitudes and longitudes based on distance.

In my case, both have similar latitudes and longitudes. For example, I have df1 on the discharge (volumetric flow rate) of points along a river and their corresponding latitudes and longitudes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,5), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), Q = c(150, 120, 80, 95, 100))
```

I also have df2 on treatment of river points and their corresponding latitudes and longitudes

```
df2 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,5), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), T = c(17, 12, 8, 9, 10))
```

I want the product to look like this:

```
Lat  Long   Q     T
2     6    150    17
4     7    120    12
1     8     80     8
2     9     95     9
5     8    100    10
```

Comment: just merge them directly on Lat and Lon: `merge(df1,df2, by=c("Lat", "Lon"))`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. Here is an `left_join` option:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Lat", "Lon"))
```

Output:

```
  Lat Lon   Q  T
1   2   6 150 17
2   4   7 120 12
3   1   8  80  8
4   2   9  95  9
5   5   8 100 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Quinten said, there are multiple options.

`dplyr::left_join()` or `base::merge()` will work for data.frames just fine.

However, if your data are spatialized (e.g. `sf` objects -- as you tagged the question), you could use `sf::st_join()` too.

```
# Your data
df1 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,5), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), Q = c(150, 120, 80, 95, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,5), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), T = c(17, 12, 8, 9, 10))

library(sf)

df1_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326)
df2_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(df2, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326)
# Join them
df_join <- sf::st_join(df1_sf, df2_sf)

# View
df_join

    Q  T    geometry
1 150 17 POINT (6 2)
2 120 12 POINT (7 4)
3  80  8 POINT (8 1)
4  95  9 POINT (9 2)
5 100 10 POINT (8 5)
```

Although, note that if the coordinates are not *exactly* the same, it won't merge as you were expecting in your question:

```
# df1 as your example
df1 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,5), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), Q = c(150, 120, 80, 95, 100))
# Change last "Lat" to 10 in df2:
df2 <- data.frame(Lat = c(2,4,1,2,10), Lon = c(6,7,8,9,8), T = c(17, 12, 8, 9, 10))

df1_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326)
df2_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(df2, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

df_join <- sf::st_join(df1_sf, df2_sf)

# View
df_join

    Q  T    geometry
1 150 17 POINT (6 2)
2 120 12 POINT (7 4)
3  80  8 POINT (8 1)
4  95  9 POINT (9 2)
5 100 NA POINT (8 5) ## Note the 'NA' value here in variable T.
```

This happens because `sf::st_join()` join attributes from arg `y` to `x` -- i.e. it behaves as a `dplyr::left_join()`, and as "Lat" don't match between objects, with will return you an 'NA' value.